# How to assign items in nested lists a variable automatically in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, list, variables

I have a spatial problem that works with coordinates in python with a list list this:

```
mList = [[0,0,0],[1000,0,600]],\
[[]],\
[[1000,1000,120]],\
[[0,0,0],[3000,4000,300],[3000,4000,720],[0,0,1020]],\
[[150,0,0],[1000,0,360], [4000,4000,660],[4000, 4000, 960],
[100,0,1320]]
```

I  need to assign automatic variables to the items before each . for example, `distance1 = [[0,0,0],[1000,0,600]], distance2=[[]], distance3= [[1000,1000,120]]` etc. However, this needs to be automatic for each distance'n' rather than me taking indexes from mList and assigning them to variable distance'n'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BTW: mList is a tuple and you can avoid the line continuations if you enclose the lot in `()`s.

I'm not quite sure why you need them as variables but if all you need is to be able to reference them via the name `distanceN` a dictionary might be sufficient:

```
>>> data = {'distance{}'.format(i+1): d for i, d in enumerate(mList)}
>>> print(data['distance1'])
[[0, 0, 0], [1000, 0, 600]]
```

Comment: I can't condone the use of `locals()` in this way, however, the dictionary method is OK. Or you could just leave it as a list and access by index which requires no work at all.

Comment: Modifying `locals()` this way is [specifically prohibited by the relevant documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals), and such modifications won't actually affect a function's local variables. Try it! `def demo(): x = 1; locals()['x'] = 2; print x`

Comment: Updated answer to remove locals()... updating globals() doesn't have the same warning. BTW it isn't prohibited it just isn't guaranteed to work - though it does it my environment.